# Can't run php script from cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run without success a cron job, I don't understand if the problem is the php file or the job string:

```
01 17 03 05 * php -f /home/mn0198/razorphyn/soup/admin/sendmailcron.php 8da0700882094bae6809f9e4b515c97f0e316870b08d2868f142345c94f9cdab /home/mn0198/razorphyn/soup
```

and this is the head of the php script:

```
require_once ($argv[2].'/Swift/lib/swift_required.php');
$filepass = $argv[2].'/config/pass.txt';
$pass=file($filepass, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$pass=$pass[1];
if($argv[1]==$pass || $argv[0]==$pass){
    $fileconfig =$argv[2].'/config/config.txt';
    $filemail =$argv[2].'/config/mail.txt';
    $filefnmail =$argv[2].'/config/fnmail.txt';
    $filefnmessage = $argv[2].'/config/fnmessage.txt';
    $filefnfooter = $argv[2].'/config/footermail.txt';
```

I tried to run it normally and it worked, but not from the Cron job schedule(also I don't receive any mail from my server)

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Change `php` for `/bin/php` or whatever comes from `which php`.

Comment: Might be wrong here, but does cron accept `01` `03` etc as timing params, or should it be `1`, `3` etc (as in no leading 0)

Comment: @fedorqui could you explain better? You mean something like this: `01 17 03 05 * /bin/php -f /home/mn0198/razorphyn/soup/admin/sendmailcron.php`?

Comment: Because my host page say this: PHP
`Command to run a PHP5 cron job:
 php /home/user_name123/public_html/cron.php

 Optional flag sometimes required for a PHP cron job:
 php -q /home/user_name123/public_html/cron.php

 Command to run a PHP4 cron job:
 /usr/local/php4/bin/php /home/user_name123/public_html/cron.php`

Comment: Yes, `01 17 03 05 * /usr/local/php4/bin/php`